# Pass variables from JavaScript to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple HTML like this:

```
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <script>var testVariable = "Hello"</script>

        <form method="post" action="/">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my Node.js looks like this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    Console.log(req.body.testVariable);
});
```

What I need to do is when the form is submitted the `testVariable` needs to be passed to the Node.js function, I'm trying with hidden fields but I'm still having problems with that, i.e:

```
<input type="hidden" name="chat" value="<script>testVariable</script>">
```

But as you can imagine it pass all the script as a string, and not the value of the variable.

Does someone knows how to do that? Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to JavaScript and Node.js in general and I can't find answers in Google.

Thanks.

**-----EDIT------**

My form now looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="chat" id="hiddenInput" />

    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById('hiddenInput');
        input.value = $('#conversation');
    </script>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And on my Node.js I'm printing the object like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.chat));
```

and it prints `"[object Object]"` (including the quotes).

I verified that the variable received is a string with:

```
console.log(typeof req.body.chat);  // prints "string"
```

Comment: The data is posted as variables named based on the `name` attribute of input elements with values defined by the elements value property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascript to target the hidden input and set the value before submitting the form:

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="chat" id="hiddenInput" />
```

**JS**

```
var input = document.getElementById('hiddenInput');
input.value = testVariable.toString();
```

Also, on your Node server, you need to access `req.body.chat` - the `body` property you want corresponds to the `name` of the input element

Comment: Hi Jordan, seems that it now is passing the object but as a string, if I print the recieved variable it prints `"[object Object]"` (inclusing the quotes), I updated the question with the new form

Comment: testVariable.toString()

Comment: How do you 'link' the NodeJS to the HTML? Sorry if this sounds like a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the input `name` attribute. And that input must be inside the `form` so you can catch it in Node:

```
<input type="hidden" name="testVariable" value="the value string">
```

Try:

```
    <form method="post" action="/">
        <input type="hidden" name="testVariable" value="the value string">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

And it should log `"the value string"` in Node.

Comment: But the problem is how can I replace the hardcoded string "the value string" with a JavaScript variable

Comment: @cesar_k13 well you could do `document.querySelector('input[name="testVariable"]').value = somevariable;` and that would pass the content of that variable into the input which will be posted. Otherwise AJAX is what you might need...